# aeotec aërQ temp/rh sensor or zwave-js not reporting state change

Tags: raspberry-pi, zwave

I have a simple iot app:

```
raspberry pi 4
aeotec Z-stick7
aeotec aërQ temp/humidity sensor
mosquitto
zwave-js-ui
```

The setup works fine, yet state changes are not being reported so often.

Yesterday evening, circa 23:00, the sensor reported 22.7 degrees to `zwave-js-ui`. This morning, circa 08:00, 19.2 degrees. No reports in between.

These measurements are accurate, however, the temperature will have fallen gradually during the night (the sensor is placed near a window that was opened partially at around 23:00 and the outdoor temperature sank till circa 8 degrees last night).

The log in the `zwave-js-ui` webapp registers no events between 23:00 yesterday and 08:00 today.

I'm guessing I need to tweek the parameter `[3-112-0-1] Temperature Change Report Threshold`?, which appears under `Control Panel -> Node -> Configuration v4`

[image: screenshot of zwave-js-ui]

But to what?

I'd like reports at least every degree of change.

It's worth pointing out that I get reports if I quick push the button on the sensor.

I found this post https://github.com/zwave-js/node-zwave-js/issues/2595, suggesting that this was an issue on older versions, called `zwavejs2mqtt`. The issue was unresolved, closed as stale.

Comment: maybe the `0.1` is incorrect and is in reality  `1.0` ... try setting the threshold to `1`

Comment: Yes, that seems to help; i'll monitor a bit more this evening then repost here. Do you want to make it an answer I can accept? Or I can do it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is an error in the software, and the resolution is not `0.1`, but it is `1.0`.

Setting the threshold to `1` may reveal such an error.

Comment: This solution worked on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop. However, on my raspeberry pi (debian) the `zwave-js-ui` interface will not save the parameter when I change it to 1. Highly frustrating. It's the pi that will be the "production" machine. I wonder if I set the parameter to '0' (disable) this will allow the device to report all changes?

Comment: Now also working on my pi; seems like I have to save the setting 2-3 times for the software to work out that I'm serious about this :)